# PCL - error C2039: 'setSize' : is not a member of 'pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visualization, point-cloud-library

I try to use pcl with visual studio 2010. I download and install `PCL 1.6.0`. I run below simple example successfully.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pcl/io/pcd_io.h>
#include <pcl/io/ply_io.h>
#include <pcl/point_types.h>

int main (int argc, char** argv)
 {
  bool binary = false;
  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud (new     pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);

 pcl::PCDReader reader;

  reader.read<pcl::PointXYZ> ("in.pcd", *cloud);

  std::cerr << "Read cloud: " << std::endl;
  std::cerr << *cloud << std::endl;

 pcl::PLYWriter plywriter;
 plywriter.write<pcl::PointXYZ> ("out.ply", *cloud, binary);

 return (0);
 }
```

But when I try [this code](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/interactive_icp.php#the-code) , I get an run time error. It says that `2>..\pclTest.cpp(162): error C2039: 'setSize' : is not a member of 'pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer'
2>          C:\Program Files\PCL 1.6.0\include\pcl-1.6\pcl/visualization/pcl_visualizer.h(86) : see declaration of 'pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer'`

Is there any function same work on PCL 1.6.0? I don't have suitable examples for PCL 1.6.0. How can I find examples for PCL 1.6.0?

**EDIT**

I downloaded pcl [from here](http://2%3E..%5CpclTest.cpp(162):%20error%20C2039:%20'setSize'%20:%20is%20not%20a%20member%20of%20'pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer'%202%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20C:%5CProgram%20Files%5CPCL%201.6.0%5Cinclude%5Cpcl-1.6%5Cpcl/visualization/pcl_visualizer.h(86)%20:%20see%20declaration%20of%20'pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer'). But I don't know how can I install and use it with visual stduio. There are many `CMakeLists.txt` files. Which one I use on Cmake and create project on cmake?

Answer (score 0):

The version you downloaded should come with its own tutorials. However, you can look at any previous version of Point Cloud Library on github (thank you, open source software). I looked up the tutorials for 1.6.0 and there is no interactive ICP tutorial for that version of ICP:

https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/tree/pcl-1.6.0rc1/doc/tutorials/content

So either upgrade or alter the code so it works with the PCLVisualizer that you do have. I would just try to change the code in the first instance.

Note. Newer versions of PCL for windows come out from time to time. E.g. http://unanancyowen.com/?p=1255&lang=en